# Error con consulta Select Option en base de datos

Tags: php, html, html5

No me funciona el select con un valor que quiero que aparezca desde la base de datos.

Tengo duda con mi codigo, lo que quiero hacer es que el valor que tiene un registro aparezca como valor primero en el select.

Mi codigo:

```
<?php
 include ("../../conexion/conectar.php");


$id=$_POST['folio'];

  $consultauniversidades= mysql_query("SELECT   iduniversidad, nombreuni FROM universidades",   $con);
$consultaalumno=mysql_query("SELECT iduniversidad   from alumnos where folio='$id'");
$row_consulta= mysql_fetch_assoc    ($consultauniversidades);
$row_alumno= mysql_fetch_assoc($consultaalumno);

     ?>
<select class="form-control" name="Universidad"     id="Universidad" required>         
<?php
      do{ 
        if($row_consulta['iduniversidad']==$row_alumno  ['iduniversidad'] )
        { ?> 
           <option   value ="<?php echo $row_consulta   ['iduniversidad']?>" selected>
          <?php echo $row_consulta['nombreuni'];?>  
        </option>
          <?php  
        } else { 
        ?>
<option value ="<?php echo $row_consulta    ['iduniversidad']?>">
          <?php echo $row_consulta['nombreuni'];?>  
        </option>

        <?php
        }
      }while ($row_consulta=mysql_fetch_assoc   ($consultauniversidades)); 
        ?>               
        </select>
```

Comment: ¿qué error te da? ¿o cuál es el problema?

Comment: No me lanza ningún error, lo que pasa es que abro una ventana modal de un registro para editar los datos , esa ventana modal tiene el formulario del registro con los datos que tiene registrados en la base de datos, entonces lo que quiero es que me muestre en el select lo que tiene guardado como registro en la base de datos, no se si me explique, entonces no entiendo porque no me funciona si en consola checo y si funciona,ayuda

Comment: lo que quieres es que tu select tenga seleccionado el valor que coincida con tu registro en la bd?

Comment: Exacto! si eso, pero no se porque no funciona en la ventana modal, no me muestra el valor seleccionado, pero checo en consola y si me muestra el select con el valor seleccionado, no se si sea porque al abrir la ventana modal se actualiza o algo asi , ayuda porfavor

Answer (score 1):

Aqui tengo la ventana modal y hasta abajo del script que es como cargo el select option a la ventana modal

```html
              <!--Comienza tabla modal para editar-->
                        <div class="container">
                <div id="tablaAlumnos"></div>
      </div>

    <!-- Modal para edicion de datos -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="modalEdicion" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Actualizar datos</h4>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
          <label>Folio</label>
          <input type="text" name="" id="folio" class="form-control input-sm" readonly="readonly">
          <label>Nombre</label>
          <input type="text" name="" id="nom" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Nombre..">
          <label>Apellido Paterno</label>
          <input type="text" name="" id="apellidopaterno" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Apellido Paterno..." >
          <label>Apellido Materno</label>
          <input type="text" name="" id="apellidomaterno" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Apellido Materno...">
          <label>Matricula</label>
          <input type="text" name="" id="matricula" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Matricula...">
            <div><label for="Universidad">Universidad: </label> </div>
        <div class="col-md-8" id="universidades">        
           
        </div>
<br>
<br>
      <label>Tipo estancia: </label>      <br>
       <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" id="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary" for="option1">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" value ="Estancia I" checked> Estancia I
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary" for = "option2">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" value ="Estancia II" > Estancia II
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary" for = "option3">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off" value ="Servicio Social" > Servicio Social
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary" for ="option4">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off" value ="Estadia" > Estadia
          </label>
      </div>   
      <br>
          <label>Grado</label>
          <input type="text" name="" id="grado" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Grado...">
          <label>CURP</label>
          <input type="text" name="" id="CURP" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="CURP...">
          <label>Correo institucional</label>
          <input type="text" name="" id="correoi" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Correo institucional...">
          <label>Correo Personal</label>
          <input type="text" name="" id="correop" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Correo Personal...">
          <label>Calle</label>
          <input type="text" name="" id="calle" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Calle...">
          <label>Colonia</label>
          <input type="text" name="" id="colonia" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Colonia...">
          <label>Municipio</label>
          <input type="text" name="" id="municipio" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Municipio...">
          <label>Codigo Postal</label>
          <input type="text" name="" id="codigopostal" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Codigo Postal...">
          <label>Estado</label>
          <input type="text" name="" id="estado" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Estado...">
          <label>NSS</label>
          <input type="text" name="" id="nss" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="NSS...">
          <label>Numero</label>          
          <input type="text" name="" id="numero" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Numero...">
          <label>Estado</label>
          <select class="form-control"  id="activo" required>         
            <option value ="1">Activo</option>        
            <option value ="0">Inactivo</option>        
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="actualizadatos" data-dismiss="modal" >Actualizar
        </button>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Termina-->                                                                                       
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#universidades').load('PHP/listaUniversidades.php');
 }); 
       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto y me avisas si te funciona, el primer while te pone el mismo id en primero y seleccionado, y el segundo while te pone el resto de la info en el select......
[mira como funciona](https://imgur.com/a/OEyyAJ1)

```js
<?php
// NO COPIAR ESTO ----------------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
$servidor="localhost";
$usuario="root";
$password="";
$basededatos="stackover";
//Conexion DB
$con = mysql_connect($servidor,$usuario,$password);
mysql_select_db($basededatos,$con);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
// NO COPIAR ESTO ----------------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
//$id="1";
// COPIAR DESDE AQUI ABAJO ----------------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

$id=$_POST['folio'];
$consultauniversidades= mysql_query("SELECT iduniversidad, nombreuni FROM universidades",$con);
$consultaalumno=mysql_query("SELECT iduniversidad from alumnos where folio='".$id."'",$con);
$row_consulta= mysql_fetch_assoc($consultauniversidades);
$row_alumno= mysql_fetch_assoc($consultaalumno);
?>
<select class="form-control" name="Universidad"     id="Universidad" required>         
<?php
while ($row_consulta=mysql_fetch_assoc ($consultauniversidades)){
if($row_consulta['iduniversidad']==$row_alumno['iduniversidad']){
echo'<option value="'.$row_consulta["iduniversidad"].'" selected>'.$row_consulta["nombreuni"].'</option>';
}}
$consultauniversidades= mysql_query("SELECT iduniversidad, nombreuni FROM universidades",$con);
while ($row_consulta=mysql_fetch_assoc ($consultauniversidades)){
if($row_consulta['iduniversidad']!=$row_alumno['iduniversidad']){
echo'<option value="'.$row_consulta["iduniversidad"].'">'.$row_consulta["nombreuni"].'</option>';
}}
?>               
</select>
```

Comment: No muestra nada en el select option, pero en consola me imprime esto: <select class="form-control" name="Universidad"     id="Universidad" required>         
<option value="2" selected>UTEZ</option>               
</select>

Comment: si en la consola te imprime eso, debe ser que tienes algún error en otra parte del código, a menos de que me haya equivocado yo en alguna comilla. Si tienes más codigo, envialo para analizarlo

Comment: ya añadi mas codigo

Comment: me puedes explicar como quieres que funcione? porque entiendo que debe hacer el input del numero de folio para que busqué en la base de datos al alumno y en que universidad esta inscrito, entonces en el select muestra como primero la universidad en que esta inscrito y de ahí el resto de las universidades. Creo que estoy en lo correcto o no? pero la pregunta es, el folio apenas se lo inserta en el formulario, lo busca automaticamente para cargar el select

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es simplemente agregar el atributo `selected` al option cuando el id coincida con el almacenado en la bd:

```
...
<select class="form-control" name="Universidad" id="Universidad" required>
    <?php foreach ($row_consulta as $universidad) :
    // sólo si los id coinciden se dibuja el option con el atributo selected
    $selected = ($universidad['iduniversidad'] == $row_alumno['iduniversidad']) ? 'selected' : '';
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $universidad['id'];?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $universidad['nombreuni'];?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
...
```